# Getting ASP.NET Source Representation of Programmatically Created Page

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im creating a page generator for ASP page. It takes XML input, and then converts it into ASPX representation.

During the process of conversion, here's some code i used,

```
var page = new Page();
var pnlUpdate = new UpdatePanel();
page.Controls.Add(pnlUpdate);
```

Theoritically, it should creates ASP file like this,

```
<% Page ...>
....
....
<asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

How do i get the source representation of my programmatically created page object? Using Filter or catching the HttpRespose output gives me the parsed HTML output, not the ASP one.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: I think it would be better to generate it as a page first, rather than using XmlWriter, is there any better ways?

Comment: Again, why would you want to create a page this way? What do you plan to do with it?

Comment: My company has some page that is similar to each others, most of them were page for CRUD some table in the database. Rather than creating new page, rewrite code for CRUD, search, displaying data, creating interfaces, it would be nice if the user just create a small and short xml file that defines what it needs to generate its aspx representation and collect resources of the database from information_schema.

Comment: But you don't need to create a .aspx. Use the XML to generate the controls you require. No .aspx markup is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no code in .Net Framework that will convert control tree into APSX page.

You can write your own version (especially if you have very limited set of allowed control/properties) by walking control tree and generating ASPX as you go. Note that you'd need to know what properties are changed from default values...

It probably would be easier to go directly from XML to ASPX, you may be even able to have XSLT transformation to do so.